# Python Create a program that performs and analysis on final grades in a course

Tags: python, list, append, average, min

The folowing are what im suppose to do 
Create a program that performs and analysis on final grades in a course.  The program must use a loop and append each grade to the list as it is added.  The program asks the user to enter the final grade (percent score as whole number) for 10 students.  The program will then display the following data:

- The highest score in the class.
- The lowest score in the class.
- The average score in the class.

I keep getting an error on line 12 and cannot figure out why.

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/COMS-170/program7.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()

  File "H:/COMS-170/program7.py", line 12, in main
    total = sum(info)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

CODE:

```
def main():
    info = get_values()
    total = sum(info)
    average = total/len(info) 
    print('Highest Grade: ', max(info))
    print('Lowest Grade: ', min(info))  
    print('Average is: ', average)

def get_values():
    num_grades = 10
    #making of the list
    grades = []
   #ask the user for the info
   print('Please enter the final grades for 10 students: ')

   #put the info into the list with a loop 
   for i in range(num_grades):
   grade = input('Enter a grade: ')
   grades.append(grade)
  return grades
main()
```

Comment: what error are you getting. is it a "unexpected indent" error ? Everything after line 12 seems like its using 3 spaces instead of 4 spaces.

Comment: @TehTris no it is a Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/COMS-170/program7.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "H:/COMS-170/program7.py", line 12, in main
    total = sum(info)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that after you read from the input, you will get a list of strings in grades variable.
So, you can use int method to parse the input:

```
grades.append(int(grade))
```

Comment: You are welcome. If you need to handle floats, the principle is the same

Answer (score 1):

Your solution needs a slight correction as your user input returns `str` values and you want to `sum` those, but first cast them to `int`s, like this:

```
def main():
    info = get_values()
    total = sum(info)
    average = total/len(info) 
    print('Highest Grade: ', max(info))
    print('Lowest Grade: ', min(info))  
    print('Average is: ', average)

def get_values():
    num_grades = 10
    #making of the list
    grades = []
    #ask the user for the info
    print('Please enter the final grades for 10 students: ')

    #put the info into the list with a loop 
    for i in range(num_grades):
        grade = int(input('Enter a grade: ')) # convert the input `str` to `int`
        grades.append(grade)
    return grades
main()
```

Also you should take care during `int` conversion that there no exception occurs, like `ValueError`.

Hope it helps!